# Cannot load settings from file

Tags: java, android

```
Load Settings
                    Cannot load settings from file 'D:\IU Folder\ContactsInListView-Android-Examples.com2_\voice-quickstart-android-master\voice-quickstart-android-master.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[21,45]
                    Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
                    Please correct the file content
```

Comment: Post your XML file.

Comment: You can try, Invalidate Caches/Restart did the trick. or somehow your xml that causes the error